# Nested table using tabulator in node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red, tabulator

can someone help me how to make nested table with tabulator in node red
really I don't find the solution how to make it its complicated.
I need it in my app and also to move row between table in node red using tabulator

I tried to make table inside each row in another table using ui table in node red and tabulator

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77422101/edit) the question to show what you've tried and how it didn't work